# make JQuery Mobile ListView so it popups Dynamically with enhanceWithin() (Context Menu)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

Hi I want to do something simple - I want JQuery Mobile popups created dynamically - and my code "works" in that it appends the html but it doesn't "JQM prepare" the html so the `popup()` call does nothing. I am inserting menus for long presses but the menu doesn't pop up correctly. These are meant to be context menus, so I need to pass parameters ( via markup `attribs` for the href's etc to work).

html

```
<a href="/folders.php?path=Dogs">
     <img src="/img/dog.png"  ref="Dogs" class="touchableFolder">
</a>
```

jquery

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $(".touchableFolder").on("taphold", function(e) { 
       $(this).append('<div data-role="popup" id="'+$(this).attr('ref')+'" data-theme="none"><ul data-role="listview"><li data-role="list-divider">Folder Menu</li><li><a href="#" data-rel="dialog">Open Folder</a></li><li><a href="#" data-rel="dialog">Rename</a></li><li><a href="#" data-rel="dialog">User Rights</a></li></ul></div>'); 
   }); 
   //need something like this here --->  $(this).JQMValidate();
   $('#'+$(this).attr('ref')).popup("open");
});
</script>
```

Comment: you want to _validate_ what exactly? Which jQM version are you using?

Comment: it's not form "validate" it's "markup re-validate"... I want to "reparse" or "action" or "attach" the JQM engine to the newly generated markup classes and tags are "really" actioned as such.. i.e. the events get attached and the JIT changes happen, as they do on page load, basically because JQM hides what it does merely adding the right tages in generated HTMl isn't enough, what I want to do is tell JQM to -re-render that markup as if it were an onload

Comment: so you want to create a popup on the fly, attach event and open it? like this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Lzsn2/

Comment: no, that's markup based, I mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/k5weF/ his is one similar that I wrote for msgboxes - most people make it far too messy and their code is far too long

Comment: this is jQuery-ui not jQM.

Comment: that's because JQM is heavily deficient - nevertheles it's the same principle I am trying to achieve. Inject markup on the fly: rerun JQM engine over it. done. most of JQM is far too long winded

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51256/discussion-between-omar-and-user26676)

Comment: Don't tag your question with [tag:jquery-validate] if your question has nothing to do with this plugin.

Comment: @Sparky, it's to do with "markup validation in jquery", and since there are well over a thousand listed plugins (let alone unlisted ones) and since the tag doesn't say, please don't get upset over a non-issue.. for instance: how many jquery-validate chaps came to this post and commented? (clue "zero") having said all that feel free to make a answer comment if it's good I will give you the mark and you can increase some gold gems (or whatever) - if 32.1k isn't enough

Comment: Clue: [I'm a "jQuery Validate" chap](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/topusers), and if you'd hover over the [tag:jquery-validate] tag you'll see that it specifically describes what it's for:  [_"The jQuery Validation plugin is a jQuery plugin by Jörn Zaefferer. Its purpose is to perform **client-side form validation**."_](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) ~ clearly that has nothing to do with _"markup validation in jquery"_.